# Changing file extension appearance on the fly

Tags: windows, winapi

I recently watched this [video](https://youtu.be/BcGArVo0JVA?t=1731) of Forcepoint DLP. The guy over there, applied an encryption policy (which encrypts files copied to USB) to files which are on USB. In windows explorer, files are shown as not encrypted but they are actually. The interesting thing is when he ejects USB and inserts to another pc (which has no DLP endpoint software of Forcepoint), files are shown with .ws suffix. Which specification of WINAPI provides this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should describe the problem here, rather than expect people to watch an off site video

Comment: Forcepoint DLP most likely has implemented a custom [Shell Namespace Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works) that knows how to display encrypted `.ws` files. And/or custom file system drivers to enforce the security policies when copying files to/from USB. The 1st PC has that Extension/driver installed, whereas the 2nd PC does not.

Comment: @david problem is they seem to magically remove the .ws suffix, and I could not find a way to describe it to google it. Thanks to Remy, I know now.

Comment: You can't use a namespace extension to *replace* the view on a removable drive such as D: or E:. what you can do with it is add another folder in the tree that display something different. Difficult to say what they're using w/o testing it.